# Direct product of localization maps is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Is the product of localization maps $$A \to \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ always injective?

I can prove it when $A$ there is no nilpotent elements, but I can't find a counter-example for the general case.

Comment: If $a\neq 0$, then the annihilator of $a$ is a proper ideal, so is contained in a maximal ideal $m$. Is $a/1=0$ in $A_m$?

Comment: Thanks, I see it's not possible.